# How to customize Devise to use username as authentication key instead of email on only one user type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two user types, admins and customers, I've been trying to make customers login with their usernames exclusively, while keeping admins unaffected(i.e., still login with their emails). I've gone through the process of dropping the email on login/register for the customers. But it turns out that the process is affecting the admins too -- they cannot login with their emails anymore.

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to change devise's configuration options at runtime from

`Config.authentication_keys = [ :username ] #For customers`

to:

`Config.authentication_keys = [ :email ] #For admins`
based on namespace.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

P.S: I tried injecting `Proc.new {#block}` to `Config.authentication_keys` to add some logic to the configuration option, but it's failing due to Devise expecting the option to be an array.

For example:

```
  config.authentication_keys = Proc.new { [ :email ] }
```

fails when sanitizing parameters with `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [..]` with this error

```
undefined method `+' for #<Proc:0x5d872a0>
```

Comment: Did you checked this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address.  Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can override your `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method for `User` model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(conditions, opts={})
  if admin?
    find_by(email: conditions[:login])
  else
    find_by(username: conditions[:login])
  end
end

# config/initializers/desvise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.authentication_keys = [:login]
```

P.S.: Example for `mongoid`, I don't rememeber how to call find for AR.